# C# how to call method for every item in a List<>

Tags: c#

I have a class:

```
[DataContract]
public class InventoryItem : NotifyPropertyChangeObject
{
    private Guid _inventoryItemUid;
    private string _description;
    private bool _isActive;

    [DataMember]
    public Guid InventoryItemUid {
        get { return _inventoryItemUid; }
        set { ApplyPropertyChange<InventoryItem, Guid>(ref _inventoryItemUid, o => o.InventoryItemUid, value); }
    }
    [DataMember]
    public string Description {
        get { return _description; }
        set { ApplyPropertyChange<InventoryItem, String>(ref _description, o => o.Description, value); }
    }
    [DataMember]
    public bool IsActive {
        get { return _isActive; }
        set { ApplyPropertyChange<InventoryItem, Boolean>(ref _isActive, o => o.IsActive, value); }
    }

    public void CustomMethod()
    {
        // here some code....
    }
}
```

In my application code I get a `List<InventoryItem>`:

```
List<Entities.InventoryItem> items = new List<Entities.InventoryItem>();

var newItem = new Entities.InventoryItem();

using (Logistics.Data.Warehouse svc = new Data.Warehouse())
{
    items = svc.GetInventoryItems().ToList();
}
```

I need to call for every item in the `List<InventoryItem>`the method `CustomMethod()`.

> What is the best way to do it in terms of performance?

I know I can do a `foreach` but if I get 5,000 rows then maybe `foreach` is not good for performance. Actually this `CustomMethod()` is like an initializer code thing.

Comment: There's no way around it you need a loop

Comment: But if you still need to call the method for each row, how does it matter if you have 5 rows or 5,000? Maybe you could explain what the method is(unless it really does something to each row, then there's no way around it).

Comment: If it needs to be called on each item, why not to put it in constructor?

Comment: The class inherits from other class that has a constructor, when I get the list from my service that constructor is never called, its only called if I create a new item of the class. So I need that constructor to be called.

Comment: So if you define constructor in InventoryItem, it is not called?

Comment: There are probably multiple ways to do this. Loops, parallelization etc etc. Have you actually measured the performance of say 5000 items and is it or is it not acceptable? And do realize that when you introduce threading of any kind you might run into thread safety issues. IMHO there is no best way. Actual measurements will help determine a fast approach. What's in `CustomMethod`?

Answer (score 1):

If your list is a huge list you can divide it in groups with 20 items and do your action in parallel on each one of them:

```
private void CustomVoid(string s)
{

}
```

And:

```
List<string> items = new List<string>();
for (int i = 0; i <= items.Count / 20; i++)
{
      List<string> smallList = items.Skip(i * 20).Take(20).ToList();
      smallList.AsParallel().ForAll(sm => CustomVoid(sm));
}
```

In comments below suggested to forget the loop and using only this:

```
items.AsParallel().ForAll(sm => CustomVoid(sm));
```

That may has better performance.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Why group it in batches of 20 items instead of just letting PLINQ determine how to optimize it?

Comment: that would be slower than just items.AsParallel

Comment: You mean this: `Parallel.ForEach(
    items,
    new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = ? },` What is your suggestion? **20** is a sample number that he must choose it by his situation. @Peter Bons.

Comment: You do not need to specify `MaxDegreeOfParallelism`, The docs at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.paralleloptions.maxdegreeofparallelism(v=vs.110).aspx give some thoughts about when to override the default setting.